# Resize and crop image using graphicsmagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm using `gm convert -geometry "XxY^>"`, this does resize the image but it doesn't crop it. Suppose I've got a 100 x 100 image and want to have a 20 x 30 version, the current command will return a 30 x 30 version. How do I crop this to 20 x 30?
Just `-crop 20x30` returns the left part, while I'd like to have the center part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set the `gravity` before cropping:

```
gm convert image.png -gravity center -crop 20x30+0+0 result.png
```

Comment: Is gm smart enough not to resize the pixels outside the cropped region?

Comment: @XTF: What?  Have you tried the command?  Also gravity may work, or just modify the region XY parameters.